# Show that, $\prod_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}(n!)^{\frac{k-1}{k^{n+1}}}\right)=\prod_{m=2}^{\infty}m^{\zeta(s)-1}$

Tags: infinite-product

The factorial n! is defined for all positive integer n as
$$n!=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots2\cdot1$$

The $\zeta(s)$ is defined for all real R(s)>1 as
$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^s}$$

Show that,

$$\prod_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}(n!)^{\frac{k-1}{k^{n+1}}}\right)=\prod_{m=2}^{\infty}m^{\zeta(m)-1}$$

Comment: First of all how is factorial be relate to the zeta function. I don't where to start, could you help

Comment: There seem to be some formulae relating the two on these pages: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Factorial.html, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html - that being said, I don't know how to solve the problem, I just figured that no one would help you until you said what you had tried so far, and hence I was trying to help you help yourself, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Correction from s to m

Comment: $\log \prod_m m^{2^{-m}} = \sum_m 2^{-m} \log m$, hence on the RHS you are considering $\sum_{k,m} k^{-m} \log k$

Comment: Because I don't it and I am collecting all the proof so I can learn them. These are my propose problems I didn't look into a book and copy them and post on here for fun. I just don't have that kind of knowledge like you guy

Comment: Anyway, by just swapping the two products in the LHS, we get: $$\prod_{n\geq 2}(n!)^{\zeta(n)-\zeta(n+1)}.$$ Can you exploit $(n+1)!=(n+1)\cdot n!$ now?

Comment: @pisquare: but that is quite against the MSE policy. We are not here for solving any problem you may find in a book. At least, give us some reason for helping you by showing your actual thoughts about the problem, not just the definitions of $n!$ and $\zeta$ (quite well-known and avoidable).

Comment: These are not book problems, they are mine and I work them out my the method of experimental mathematics skills I pick up. Skill of proving I am very lack in it. I just need verifications.  I have ask a lot of people for help and they couldn't until I saw this site and it is very very helpful. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: @pisquare: I do not understand, if these problems do not come from some book, how can you claim such identities without having any idea about proving them?

Comment: I just told you I am good at experimental mathematics skill, good at spotting patterns and I just verify it with a calculator. Once the numerical value match with what I assume iof the formulas, then I just assume the formula is correct until proving other wise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39242/discussion-between-pisquare-and-jack-daurizio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$ \sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{k-1}{k^{n+1}} = \zeta(n)-\zeta(n+1) $$
we have:
$$ \prod_{k\geq 2}\prod_{n\geq 0}n!^{\frac{k-1}{k^{n+1}}} = \prod_{n\geq 2}(n!)^{\zeta(n)-\zeta(n+1)} = \exp\sum_{n\geq 2}\left(\zeta(n)-\zeta(n+1)\right)(\log n!) $$
and the last series equals
$$ \sum_{m\geq 2}\left(\zeta(m)-1\right) \log(m) $$
by summation by parts. The claim easily follows.